# Quantum algorithm for AES?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, resource-request, cryptography

We all know about Shor's algorithm to attack RSA but what is the state of the art for attacking symetric algorithm such as AES today with quantum computers ?

What are the most promising papers on this today ?

Comment: You might have better luck asking over at crypto.stackexchange. Grover always works for symmetric-key cryptography.

Answer (score 3):

I think Grover's search algorithm is still the state of the art for attacking AES.

- [Implementing Grover oracles for quantum key search on AES and LowMC](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.01700) (arXiv:1910.01700, Table 8) gives logical estimates for resource counts required for breaking AES
- [Quantum Analysis of AES](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/683) (Cryptology ePrint Archive, Paper 2022/683, Table 7) then offers updates on those numbers
- You can use [Quantum Resource Estimation and Cryptography](https://quantum.microsoft.com/en-us/experience/quantum-cryptography) site to explore physical resource estimates obtained for different cryptographic algorithms under different assumptions about quantum computers used to run them, and it includes estimates for AES based on these two papers.

Comment: I would also mention this paper which gives some estimates concerning AES and a new framework for attacking it: https://tosc.iacr.org/index.php/ToSC/article/view/8314/7663